# Rasa Core TypeError (chatbot)

Tags: python, tensorflow, chatbot, rasa-core

I have an issue with RasaStack core : when I train the dialog data with this command :

```
python -m rasa_core.train -d domain.yml -s data\stories.md -o models\current\dialogue -c config.yml
```

I have this Exception TypeError :

```
    q, r = gen_linalg_ops.qr(a, full_matrices=False)
  File "C:\Users\lpschaub\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_linalg_ops.py", line 1613, in qr
    "Qr", input=input, full_matrices=full_matrices, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\lpschaub\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 609, in _apply_op_helper
    param_name=input_name)
  File "C:\Users\lpschaub\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 60, in _SatisfiesTypeConstraint
    ", ".join(dtypes.as_dtype(x).name for x in allowed_list)))
TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'input' has DataType float16 not in list of allowed values: float64, float32, complex64, complex128
```

It is obviously an tensorflow error but it is supposed to be the example code and it ain't work...

Any clue ?

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be entering input data that is 16 bit floating point, whereas the model cannot accept that. Try converting the input to one of the supported types.

Comment: hello thanks for your answer but it is not meant to be changed I think, because it's just the demo of rasa stack.. It should work..

Answer (score 0):

Please consider updating to the stable Rasa version `1.x`, e.g. by doing `pip install rasa`, where this bug is fixed.